# Computer Hangs on running this javascript code in browser

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a function in JavaScript for practice and the following code doesn't seem to be executing properly or as intended in the browser.The browser just keeps showing the busy sign and the computer literally hangs.Can anyone help me out with thius code or what the problem is:

```
function recluse() {
  return " It is\ncalled Data.\n\nData is made of merely bits, yet it takes complex forms. Control\nconsists only of simple instructions, yet it performs difficult\ntasks. From the small and trivial, the large and complex arise.\n\nThe program source is Data. Control arises from it. The Control\nproceeds to create new Data. The one is born from the other, the\nother is useless without the one. This is the harmonious cycle of\nData and Control.\n\nOf themselves, Data and Control are without structure. The programmers\nof old moulded their programs out of this raw substance. Over time,\nthe amorphous Data has crystallised into data types, and the chaotic\nControl was restricted into control structures and functions.\n\n%% Short Sayings\n\nWhen a student asked Fu-Tzu about the nature of the cycle of Data and\nControl, Fu-Tzu replied 'Think of a compiler, compiling itself.'\n\nA student asked 'The programmers of old used only simple machines and\nno programming languages, yet they made beautiful programs. Why do we\nuse complicated machines and programming languages?'. Fu-Tzu replied\n'The builders of old used only sticks and clay, yet they made\nbeautiful huts.'\n\nA hermit spent ten years writing a program. 'My program can compute\nthe motion of the stars on a 286-computer running MS DOS', he proudly\nannounced. 'Nobody own a 286-computer or uses MS DOS anymore.', Fu-Tzu\nresponded.\n\nFu-Tzu had written a small program that was full of global state and\ndubious shortcuts. Reading it, a student asked 'You warned us against\nthese techniques, yet I find them in your program. How can this be?'\nFu-Tzu said 'There is no need to fetch water hose when the house is\nnot on fire.'{This is not to be read as an encouragement of sloppy\nprogramming, but rather as a warning against neurotic adherence to\nrules of thumb.}\n\n%% Wisdom\n\nA student was complaining about digital numbers. 'When I take the root\nof two and then square it again, the result is already inaccurate!'.\nOverhearing him, Fu-Tzu laughed. 'Here is a sheet of paper. Write down\nthe precise value of the square root of two for me.'\n\nFu-Tzu said 'When you cut against the grain of the wood, much strength\nis needed. When you program against the grain of a problem, much code\nis needed.'\n\nTzu-li and Tzu-ssu were boasting about the size of their latest\nprograms. 'Two-hundred thousand lines', said Tzu-li, 'not counting\ncomments!'. 'Psah', said Tzu-ssu, 'mine is almost a *million* lines\nalready.' Fu-Tzu said 'My best program has five hundred lines.'\nHearing this, Tzu-li and Tzu-ssu were enlightened.\n\nA student had been sitting motionless behind his computer for hours,\nfrowning darkly. He was trying to write a beautiful solution to a\ndifficult problem, but could not find the right approach. Fu-Tzu hit\nhim on the back of his head and shouted '*Type something!*' The student\nstarted writing an ugly solution. After he had finished, he suddenly\nunderstood the beautiful solution.\n\n%% Progression\n\nA beginning programmer writes his programs like an ant builds her\nhill, one piece at a time, without thought for the bigger structure.\nHis programs will be like loose sand. They may stand for a while, but\ngrowing too big they fall apart{Referring to the danger of internal\ninconsistency and duplicated structure in unorganised code.}.\n\nRealising this problem, the programmer will start to spend a lot of\ntime thinking about structure. His programs will be rigidly\nstructured";
}

var para=recluse().split("\n\n");
function reduce(func,length,array)
{
    array.forEach(function(c)
                           {
                               length=func(length,c);
                           });
    return length;
}

<!---TOP LEVEL FUNCTION FOR PROCESSING A VALUE WITH A FUNCTION AND CREATING  AN ARRAY OF TH RESULTS------------>

function map(func,array)
{
    var result_array=[];

    array.forEach(function(c)
                           {
                               result_array.push(func(c));
                           });
   return result_array;
}

<!-------------THE ALGORITHM FOR FINDING THE EMPHASISED TEXT AND THE FOOTNOTES WITHIN THE TEXT---->

function fragmenter(text)
{
                var fragments=[];

                function indexing(char)
                {
                    var index=text.indexOf(char);
                    if(index==-1)
                    {
                        return text.length;
                    }
                    else
                    return index;
                }

                function ifAtStart(char)
                {
                    var end=(char,1);
                       if(end==-1)
                       {
                           throw Error("No enclosing "+char);
                       }
                    var part=text.slice(1,end);
                    text=text.slice(end+1);
                    return part;
                }

                function normalText(text)
                {
                    var end=reduce(Math.min,text.length,map(indexing,["*","{"]));//to check that the index is within the text only
                    var part=text.slice(0,end);
                    var text=text.slice(end);
                    return part;
                }

                while(text!="")        <!---4------> 
                {
                    if(text.charAt(0)=="*")
                    {
                        fragments.push({type:"emphasised",
                                       content:isAtFirst("*")});
                    }
                    else if(text.charAt(0)=="{")
                    {
                        fragments.push({type:"footnotes",
                                       content:isAtFirst("}")});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fragments.push({type:"Normal",
                                       content:normalText(text)});
                    }
                }
return fragments;               
}

console.log(fragmenter(para[1]));
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated, maybe not, but you can't (well, shouldn't) use HTML-style comments in Javascript.

`/* this is a comment */`

`window.location = "http://google.com" // this is a comment`

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I was under the impression that this was added just for the question but, just in case, this may be useful !

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I know that. Just was coding alongwith HTML so I typed it in. Thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 6):

There :

```
while(text!="")
{
     // some code that doesn't change "text"
}
```

There is no way for text to change in the loop so your code can't finish.

If you're trying to iterate over the chars, you may do this :

```
for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
     if (text.charAt(i)=="*")
```

But I wonder if you missed the fact that when you call `normalText(text)`, the `normalText` function can't change the variable it has, but only its own. You must share text. A solution is this :

```
 function normalText() // REMOVED text SO IT USES THE ONE OF THE ENCLOSING SCOPE
            {
                var end=reduce(Math.min,text.length,map(indexing,["*","{"]));//to check that the index is within the text only
                var part=text.slice(0,end);
                var text=text.slice(end);
                return part;
            }

 while(text!="")        
            {
                if(text.charAt(0)=="*")
                {
                    fragments.push({type:"emphasised",
                                   content:isAtFirst("*")});
                }
                else if(text.charAt(0)=="{")
                {
                    fragments.push({type:"footnotes",
                                   content:isAtFirst("}")});
                }
                else
                {
                    fragments.push({type:"Normal",
                       content:normalText()}); // REMOVED PASSING TEXT
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ah, `while () {/*...*/}` loops, the accidental-occasional bane of JavaScript coders everywhere..!

Comment: If your code hangs always look for loops or recursion to be the culprit first, then consider other areas.

Comment: Just like the browser, I can't guess your goal. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to find the text between two * or {} for a given piece of text.and then put them into array(fragments) as object.

Comment: @dystroy I am trying to find the text between two * or {} for a given piece of text.and then put them into array(fragments) as object.

Comment: I think I understood your intent. Look at the edit (I didn't look at the algorithm to see if it's sound).

Comment: @dystroy yes the "for" loop is working fine. Thank you. Is there a way to do it with a while lop also ??

Comment: The while loop is more prone to error if you're iterating over a string (or another collection) instead of just watching a condition.

Comment: @dystroy But the for loop is creating the same objects text.length times in the array.I  want  one text line/para to be resolved into different objects within the array according to where they occur in the text i.e. if the text is "Hello \*how\* are you", it should create three objects one containing  'Hello' and 'are you' and other containing the text between the *s.

Comment: @dystroy Also using the enclosing scopes gives an error that cant find property 'length' for the undefined